# Pyspark: Merging lists which are in dataframe column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as shown below. I want to merge the lists if they have atleast one same value. It is okay to take any of the component number. For example, **[1,2]** and **[1,4,9]** has **1** as common value. So both will be merged to **[1,2,4,9]**. Now **[1,2]** has component number **80** and and **[1,4,9]** has component number **30**. For **[1,2,4,9]** it is okay to have any one of them as component number. In the example given below, I have considered **30**.

[image]

It is possible to have a solution using dataframe or rdd operation avoiding as much iteration as possible? Thanks.